# JQM programmatically RENAMING controlgroup's legend

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I just want to rename programmatically the text of the legend with id=item_30

```
<fieldset data-role='controlgroup'>

    <legend id='item_30'>JS</legend>

    <input id ='Server1' type='radio' name='Serveridor' value='1' onclick=DefinirServer('www.rotatorsurvey.com') ><label for='Server1'>www.encuesta.ws</label>
    <input id ='Server2' type='radio' name='Serveridor' value='2' onclick=DefinirServer('www.rotatortablet.com') ><label for='Server2'>www.onlinesurvey.co</label>


</fieldset>
```

I tried:

document.getElementById('Item_30').innerHTML = 'hello guys';

BUT CHROME DRAMATICALLY CHASH and says: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById` is case-sensitive. Change to:

```
document.getElementById('item_30').innerHTML = 'hello guys';
```

Comment: No Sir, I already checked that: Chrome says: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Comment: Well, that's because Chrome can't find the element. Try this: `alert(document.getElementById('item_30'))`. Do you get an element? My code is working fine, check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kristofferj/ussKN/

Answer (score 0):

This definitely should work http://jsfiddle.net/7hgDQ/:

```
document.getElementById('item_30').innerHTML = 'hello guys';
```